Determining work done by a conveyor belt without knowing coefficient of friction
Let some bag of mass 15kg move with a constant speed without slipping up a conveyor belt inclined 30 degrees. If the bag moves a distance of 6.5m, how much work is done by the conveyor belt on the bag?
I believe that since the bag moves with a constant speed, the net work on the bag is $0J$, with gravity doing approximately -478J of work on the bag. However, I don't see how it's possible to determine the exact amount of work done by friction and the conveyor belt. The only work on the bag is being done by gravity, the conveyor belt, and friction, so the sum of the work done by the belt and friction must be 478$J$, but I don't know what other relation holds between the conveyor belt and friction to make this solvable.
Just explain the concept that makes the problem solvable; I obviously don't want the solution.


The only work on the bag is being done by gravity, the conveyor belt, and friction, so the sum of the work done by the belt and friction must be 478, but I don't know what other relation holds between the conveyor belt and friction to make this solvable.

You're drawing a distinction between "the work done by friction on the bag" and "the work done by the conveyor belt on the bag".  But the conveyor belt exerts a force on the bag via friction.  In other words, "the work done by friction" and "the work done by the conveyor belt" are one and the same thing, and are equal to 478 J.

The friction itself does nothing because the bag does not move vs the belt.

@fraxinus The contact point does move, so in the reference frame where the belt is moving, the static friction does work.  Your statement would be correct in the frame where the belt is at rest, though.  See How can static friction do work?

@fraxinus Michael is correct. In order for a force to do work on a object it must displace the object at the point of contact with the force. It's a requirement in order for energy to be transferred from the source of the force. Here static friction does that. But that's not always the case. When static friction from the road enables a car to accelerate it does no work because there is no displacement of the wheel at the point of application of the static friction force.

@BobD ok, ok - work is not frame invariant.

@fraxinus it’s more than not being frame invariant. Frame invariant means the amount  of work is the same in all frames. If the force doesn’t displace material at the point of application, the work is zero in any frame.

If the bag starts and ends at rest over the distance covered there is no change in kinetic energy of the bag. Thus, per the work energy theorem, the net work done on it is zero. That means the positive work done on the bag by the static friction force equals the negative work done on the bag by the force of gravity.
The energy of the negative work done by gravity is stored as gravitational potential energy of the Earth-bag system.
Keep in mind that the energy for the work done by the static friction force comes from the conveyer belt motor. The role of static friction is to enable the force developed by the motor on the belt to be transmitted to the package without the package slipping on the belt. If the belt were frictionless the package wouldn’t move.

Determining work done by a conveyor belt without knowing coefficient
of friction

Regarding the title of your post, if only static (not kinetic) friction is doing work, then the coefficient of friction is not involved.
However, in order for no slipping to occur, the static friction force cannot exceed the maximum possible static friction force, which is a function of the coefficient of static friction, $\mu_{s}$, as follows
$$f_{max}=\mu_{s}mg\cos\theta$$
Hope this helps.

There is no work done by friction on the bag since there is no slipping. You are correct that the net work is zero so something must cancel out the work done by gravity, and that would be the work done by whatever is powering the belt, e.g. a motor.

Friction does no work in a frame where the belt is at rest (whether slipping or not).   But in other frames, it can do work.

I revealed the answer because I still couldn't figure it out. The apparent answer is that the work due to friction is 478J, the work due to the normal force is 0, the work due to the conveyor belt is 478J, the work due to gravity is -478J, and magically, 478+478-478=0, since the answer key says the net work is 0J.

@BowlOfRed Right, my mistake, I was viewing work done by friction as energy being dissipated into heat.

Forces and distances can be resolved into x and y components.
$$W = \vec F \cdot \vec d = Fd\cos \theta = F_xd_x+F_yd_y$$
There is no force in the x direction and the distance in the y direction is $d\sin \theta$
$$W_g = -mgd\sin\theta$$
The force due to friction along the conveyor belt is balanced by the gravitational force along the conveyor belt (no slipping). Note the direction of the friction force is in the direction of motion;
$$F_f = mg\sin \theta$$
The work done by friction is
$$W_f = mgd\sin \theta$$
The total work done by friction and gravity is zero

I really don't remember learning about the "normal force", but I see it a lot in questions.
For something like a linear conveyor belt, where the velocity $\vec v$ satisfies, by definition:
$$ \vec v \cdot \hat n = 0 $$
so that the "normal force"
$$ \vec F_n = F_n\hat n $$
must satisfy:
$$ \vec F_n \cdot \vec v = F_n(\vec v \cdot \hat n) = 0 $$
The normal force doesn't do any work.
That leaves us with a friction force that is parallel to $\vec v$, so the work it does:
$$ W = \int_{x_i}^{x_f} \vec F_f \cdot d\vec x =
F_f(x_f - x_i)
$$
Of course, my $x$-coordinate is parallel to the conveyor belt, and the question is ambiguous...does the box move $d=6.5$m horizontally, or a total of $L=6.5$m?
All that really matters is how much higher is the box? The work is done by the only available force that does work: friction, and that is:
$$ W = mg(h_f - h_i) = mg\Delta h$$
and the solution means
$$ \Delta h = \frac d 2 $$
Who writes these questions...this is from a textbook?
